# Using Spark Data Frame or GlobalTempView with PySpark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new to Spark. **I managed to pass a PySpark Data Frame (created in %python context) to a Spark Data Frame (to be used in a Scala cell). But what I need to know is how to do the opposite: use a Data Frame created in a %python context in a Scala cell.**

Here are the details. I have read two tables in txt files and passed them to PySpark Dataframes. I also passed them to GlobalTempViews.

```
%python

#Pass txt curated files to Data Frames
df_a = spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").csv(curated_path_a) 
df_b = spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").csv(curated_path_b) 

df_a.createOrReplaceTempView("df_a")
df_b.createOrReplaceTempView("df_b")
```

Then I needed to use scala code so I passed the PySpark Data Frames to spark tables

```
//Passing Pyspark Data Frames to Spark Data Frames
val df_a = spark.table("df_a")
val df_b = spark.table("df_b")
```

Then I joined those tables and got another Data Frame caled df_joined_tables. I passed it to a GlobalTempView.

```
//Creating scala variables for each table
var table_name_a = dbutils.widgets.get("table_name_a")
var table_name_b = dbutils.widgets.get("table_name_b")

//Create scala variable for Join ID
var join_id = dbutils.widgets.get("table_name_b") + "ID"
//var join_id = table_name_b + "ID"

// Define join type
var join_type = dbutils.widgets.get("join_type")

// Joining Tables
var df_joined_tables = df_a
                                     .join(df_b,                                               
                                               df_a(join_id)===df_b(join_id),
                                              join_type
                                          ).select($"df_a.*",$"df_b.Description".alias(table_name_b))

df_joined_tables.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("df_joined_tables")
display(df_joined_tables)
```

Now I need to use this df_joined_tables in a %python context.  I am trying the following code but I get and error "Table or view not found: df_joined_tables". How can I fix it? Thank you in advance!

```
%python
df_joined_tables = spark.table("df_joined_tables")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the Global Temp view you need to use global_temp as keyword before your table name.
In your case try this:

```
%python
df_joined_tables = spark.table("global_temp.df_joined_tables")
```